# How do I write a robust structural search template to report Mockito times(1)/Times(1) passed to verify in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, mockito, structural-search

In my project `Mockito.times(1)` is often used when verifying mocks:

```java
verify(mock, times(1)).call();
```

This is redundant since Mockito uses implicit `times(1)` for `verify(Object)`, thus the following code does exactly what the code above does:

```java
verify(mock).call();
```

So I'm going to write an a structural search drive inspection to report such cases (let's say, named something like *Mockito.times(1) is redundant*). As I'm not an expert in IntelliJ IDEA structural search, my first attempt was:

```
Mockito.times(1)
```

Obviously, this is not a good seach template because it ignores the call-site. Let's say, I find it useful for the following code and I would not like the inspection to trigger:

```java
VerificationMode times = Mockito.times(1);
                      // ^ unwanted "Mockito.times(1) is redundant"
```

So now I would like to define the context where I would like the inspection to trigger. Now the inspection search template becomes:

```
Mockito.verify($mock$, Mockito.times(1))
```

Great! Now code like `verify(mock, times(1)).call()` is reported fine (if `times` was statically imported from `org.mockito.Mockito`). But there is also one thing. `Mockito.times` actually comes from its `VerificationModeFactory` class where such verification modes are grouped, so the following line is ignored by the inspection:

```java
verify(mockSupplier, VerificationModeFactory.times(1)).get();
```

My another attempt to fix this one was something like:

```
Mockito.verify($mock$, $times$(1))
```

where:

- `$mock$` is still a default template variable;
- `$times$` is a variable with *Text/regexp* set to `times`, *Whole words only* and *Value is read* are set to `true`, and `Expression type (regexp)` is set to `(Times|VerificationMode)` -- at least this is the way I believed it should work.

Can't make it work. Why is `Times` also included to the regexp? This is the real implementation of `*.times(int)`, so, ideally, the following line should be reported too:

```java
verify(mockSupplier, new Times(1)).get();
```

Of course, I could create all three inspection templates, but is it possible to create such a template using single search template and what am I missing when configuring the `$times$` variable?

(I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following search query:
`Mockito.verify($mock$, $Qualifier$.times(1))`

With `$Qualifier$` text/regexp `VerificationModeFactory|Mockito` and occurrences count 0,1 (to find it when statically imported also).

To also match `new Times(1)` you can use the following query:
`Mockito.verify($mock$, $times$)`

With `$times$` text/regexp `.*times\s*\(\s*1\s*\)` and uncheck the `Case sensitive` checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that's working! I would like to ask: is it possible to let the `new Times(1)` constructor also be included to the same inspection somehow?

Comment: I have added a way to find `new Times(1)` also to my answer.

Comment: Oh, structural search seems to be heavy text/regex-oriented. I thought it's not. I would like to use your first suggestion and split it to two modifications: methods and the constructors just giving them different names. Thank you!

Comment: It's actually only heavy text/regex-oriented if you are trying to search for more than one thing at the same time;-)